# ¿Como se une un Windows10 a AzureAAD?

Tags: azure, vpn

Estoy intentando unir una laptop con windows 10 a mi AzureADDs con fines académicos, pero no soy capaz de lograrlo.

El escenario hasta ahora es el siguiente: Existen 2 Resource Groups, uno para almacenar el AADDs y otro para almacenar la GateWay con la VPN.
Ya tengo configurada la VPN P2S y funciona, ademas al encontrarse las dos redes en Hub and Spoke, soy capaz de hacer ping desde la Laptop a uno de los domain controlers.

Aqui es donde viene el quebradero de cabeza, cada vez que intento unir el equipo al dominio no me deja diciendo lo siguiente

> El dominio especificado no existe o no se pudo poner en contacto con él

He mirado que el NGS del AADDs tenga las reglas necesarias para el trafico de red y las tiene, he añadido a la Vnet de la gateway por donde se conectan los usuarios las dns apuntando a los domain controllers, he vuelto a revisar por decima vez los peerings entre las redes, pero nada de nada.

¿Alguien sabe algo al respecto y me puede echar una mano?

Comment: ¿Necesitas que la laptop se conecte a tu Vnet o que la laptop se una al Microsoft Entra ID (Antiguo Azure AD)? o ¿te estas refiriendo al Azure Active Directory Domain Service? ¿Pudieras compartir un diagrama de tu red/Recursos?

Comment: Gracias Carlos, pero entre prueba y prueba al final lo he hecho con una VPN S2S